# Crystal Reports XI - Cannot edit Parameter Field

Tags: crystal-reports

I am doing some work on a Crystal Report which has been developed by someone else, I need to change a parameter Field (Within a subreport) but when I right click, there is no option to edit.

[image]

However, when I create a new parameter, I am able to right click and edit

[image]

How do I edit the existing parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A linked parameter cannot be edited.
It is created as a by-product of creating subreport links.